# C# Image Segmentation

Tags: c#, image, emgucv, image-segmentation, aforge

I have a group of PDFs that each have images embedded within them. These images usually consist of multiple elements like graphs and sub-images (biological cell and microscopic samples) with the sub-images clearly separated from one another by low entropy white space.

I have been able to extract the images stored within the PDFs but I now need to further segment these images into separate files based on viable points of interest within them (points of interest would be the rectangular sub-images and **not** the charts/graphs). An example of some of these PDF images can be seen [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22284765) under "Images from this publication".

I understand that libraries like emguCV and aForge.net that offer watershedding and k-means clustering may be able to assist in my endeavour, but as my image processing knowledge is limited I do not know exactly where to start. Also the majority of the examples I've seen online only overlay a segmented mask onto the original image instead of physically splitting the file.

Any guidance or pointers to achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you define what determines "viable points of interest"?

Comment: @James This would be far easier if I could upload an image... Nevertheless, this [link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22284765) shows examples of some of the PDF images I maybe encountering. Where it says "Images from this publication" you can see that some of these images contain tiled rectangular sub-images along with some charts/graphs. The points of interest would only be these sub-images and not the charts/graphs.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean for that one example, but computers are about absolute logical rules for doing things.  If you can't even describe linguistically how it should split the image, there is little hope of writing code to do so.